# How does ApplicationAutoScaling work for lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am working on AWS lambda and deployed it with cloudformation. Recently I read some cf template which use lambda as the target for `ApplicationAutoScaling` like below configuration.

Based on my understanding, lambda is scaled automatically and I can configure provisioned concurrency or reserved concurrency if I want to control the concurrency of lambda. But what does it mean if I put lambda as the target of `ApplicationAutoScaling`.

```
PCTargetHello:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
    DependsOn: HelloProvConcLambdaAlias
    Properties: 
      MaxCapacity: 10
      MinCapacity: 1
      ResourceId: function:${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-hello:provisioned
      RoleARN: arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/lambda.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_LambdaConcurrency
      ScalableDimension: lambda:function:ProvisionedConcurrency
      ServiceNamespace: lambda
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for managing your **provisioned concurrency** (PC). If you do as you wrote:

> I can configure provisioned concurrency or reserved concurrency if I want to control the concurrency of lambda.

then you have to adjust PC manually each time you think you will require more or less PC. With `ApplicationAutoScaling` you can **automate management of PC**. So you can setup a scheduled policy to reduce your PC, lets at, at night or weekends, or automatically increase it based on your lambda function usage.

Comment: Is there a way for me to make the PC to be 0 during night by using auto scale?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao I don't see a reason why not. AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-autoscaling.html#scenario-app-as-template-examples) have examples of scheduled actions for lambda.

Comment: but 0 is an invalid value for PC

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Then, it seems you can't do this.

Comment: @Jens Could you please clarify? You always pay for provisioned capacity, even if your function is not running.

Comment: @Marcin That's actually true. Totally forgot about it. My bad.